# how to translate normal sql to calcite avatica sql

Tags: mysql, druid, apache-calcite

I'm using Avatica as a JDBC driver to query a Druid DB but I found it doesn't support MYSQL-like paging syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA limit 4, 5
```

It only supports syntax like

```
SELECT * FROM tableA limit 2
```

How do I write the paging SQL with Avatica?

reference: http://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `LIMIT 4, 5` you can use `OFFSET 4 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY`. However, the next version of Calcite (1.14.0), which will be released within the next couple weeks, will support the MySQL style of limits you described.

Comment: In addition to the standard SQL syntax Michael mentioned, Calcite also supports PostgreSQL syntax, `LIMIT 5 OFFSET 4`. Take your pick!

Comment: Thanks @Michael  but I found another sql issue that the number of  elements  after  'IN' syntax is limited ,it return error once exceed 19.  For example, sql  "SELECT * FROM ds1 WHERE city_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)"  works, but  sql "SELECT * FROM ds1 WHERE city_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19, 20)" will return error,

Comment: Thanks @Julian , the PostgreSql syntax looks more simple, is it also supported by Calcite 1.14.0 + ?

Comment: @rellocswood Yes, that is also supported. If you have a separate problem with `IN`, you should ask a new question.

Comment: See https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html for syntax. ORDER BY is under "query:".

Comment: I can't reproduce the "IN" problem. If you have a reproducible test case please log a bug at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CALCITE and include the error stack.